# How to add app shortcuts in my app

Tags: android

I have been looking into building a app to replace the homescreen on android, I need to know how to add the option to add app shortcut to my app.

Comment: You get a list of the apps installed, get their icon and render it onto the screen.

Answer (score 0):

In your app's manifest file (AndroidManifest.xml), find an activity whose intent filters are set to the `android.intent.action.MAIN` action and the `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` category.

Add a `<meta-data>` element to this activity that references the resource file where the app's shortcuts are defined:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.myapplication">
  <application ... >
    <activity android:name="Main">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
                 android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

You can find the rest here - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html

Hope this helps!